# How to account for multiple measurements of same person in one-sample test?

Tags: t-test

I have 16 subjects, each with two measurements of the same variable (test score over two different sessions). I want to know if test score is different from zero.

I would simply aggregate this data into 32 data points and do a one-sample t-test. However, I have two measurements for each subject, which violates the independence of samples assumption. How do I account for the two samples per subject?

Comment: This sounds like a repeated measures (one sample) t-test to me. Why do you have 32 data points when you aggregate?

Comment: what are you testing? Anyway, 32 datapoints and one sample t-test doesn;t make sense

Comment: It sounds like this is a classic setup for a paired *t* test.  1) You could find the difference between the value for each session, for each participant.  In this case, you would 16 differences, equal to the number of subjects.  A one-sample *t* test could then be applied.  2) You could do a paired *t* test.  This should yield the same result as in 1).  There are assumptions that make results of this test valid, which should be considered.